# Google Maps Android studio

Tags: android, google-maps

Как одним нажатием кнопки вызвать из своего приложения стандартное приложение Google Maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, чтобы Google Maps открылся на Красной Площади в Москве, на события нажатия кнопки сажаем такой код:

```
Uri intentUri = Uri.parse("geo:55.754661,37.619604"); //координаты Красной Площади
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps"); //пакет Google Maps
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
    startActivity(mapIntent); //если есть Google Maps
else {
    //иначе запускаем дефолтное мап приложение
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intentUri));
}
```